# Why isnt my value being returned in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a `validate()` function in JavaScript, and when I invoke the method it returns `undefined` .... everything in my code looks right to me, why is it doing that?

```
function validate() {
    var __self = this;
    __self.is_valid = true;

    $(document).on("click", "#login,#create_account", function() {
        var email = $("#email").val(),
            password = $("#password").val();

        if (email == "") {
            $("#email-err-msg").removeClass("hidden").html("Enter an email address");
            __self.is_valid = false;
        } else {
            $("#email-err-msg").addClass("hidden")
        }

        return __self.is_valid;
    });
}

(function logUser() {
    $(document).on("submit", "form", function() {
        var action = $(".action").attr("data-account-action");

        console.log(validate());

        if (!validate()) {
            return false;
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: When asking for help, it's useful if you present your code in a tidy, easy-to-read way. The above has wildly inconsistent formatting, lots of pointless blank lines causing the block to scroll when it doesn't need to, odd long series of spaces for no apparent reason (as after `var action =`), etc. (I've fixed it for you on this occasion.)

Comment: The code doesn't make a lot of sense. Why are you hooking up an event handler in a function intended to be called in response to an event?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You are right. I didn't even realize I was doing it wrong. I removed the event handler and just made it a regular function and invoked it on the form submit event handler.. that worked. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `validate` function never returns anything, so the result of calling it is always `undefined`. You have a callback to an event handler that you define within it, and you have a `return` statement in *that*, but none in `validate`.

It's not clear why you are hooking up an event handler every time the user tries to submit a form. I would suggest not doing that. Perhaps something like:

```
function validate() {
    var is_valid = true;

    var email = $("#email").val(),
        password = $("#password").val();

    if (email == "") {
        $("#email-err-msg").removeClass("hidden").html("Enter an email address");
        is_valid = false;
    } else {
        $("#email-err-msg").addClass("hidden")
    }

    return is_valid;
}

(function logUser() {
    $(document).on("submit", "form", function() {
        var action = $(".action").attr("data-account-action");

        return validate();
    });
})();
```

I've removed the `click` event handler as I couldn't see that there was any reason for it, removed the global variable `__is_valid`,<sup>1</sup> and returns the result of calling `validate` directly from the `submit` handler (since returning `true` is harmless).

---

<sup>1</sup> Why was it a global variable? Because you were calling validate like this: `validate()`, which means that within the call, `this` refers to the global object (unless you're using strict mode, in which case it would be `undefined`; but I know you aren't because you said it returned `undefined` rather than throwing an error). Adding properties to the global object creates global variables.

Comment: You are right. I didn't even realize I was doing it wrong. I removed the event handler and just made it a regular function and invoked it on the form submit event handler.. that worked. Thanks for pointing that out